# How to fix this force cast in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, option-type

I am facing this below issue in my project, kindly help me to fix this issue.

> Force Cast Violation: Force casts should be avoided. (force_cast)

```
var guestNetworks: [WanNetworks] {
    for result in items ?? [] {
        for networks in result.networks ?? [] {
            print(" guest network is :: ", networks)
            return result.networks?.filter({$0.isGuest}) as! [WanNetworks] //--> In this line I am facing the issue
        }
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: This is not a compiler warning but a swiftlint warning (error) so either fix the issue or read the documentation for swiftlint to decide how to handle this warning from a swiftlint perspective. As for fixing the issue, what should happen if `networks` is nil?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering arises from the use of force casting (as!). It's always a good practice in Swift to avoid force casting because if the cast fails, it will cause a runtime crash. As Joakim Danielson sais: "*this is not a compiler warning but a swiftlint warning (error) so either fix the issue or read the documentation for swiftlint to decide how to handle this warning from a swiftlint perspective*."

To fix the issue and safely get the value you need, consider using conditional casting (as?) and providing a default value with the nil-coalescing operator (??).

Here's a safer version of your code:

```
var guestNetworks: [WanNetworks] {
    for result in items ?? [] {
        for networks in result.networks ?? [] {
            print(" guest network is :: ", networks)
            if let filteredNetworks = result.networks?.filter({$0.isGuest}) as? [WanNetworks] {
                return filteredNetworks
            }
        }
    }
    return []
}
```